# Auto adjust div height with CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's say there is six divs one on the other.

1st, 2nd and 3rd div has a fixed height e.g. 25px, 100px and 25px.
4th div is content area and should be an auto adjusting div.
5th div has some content and the min-height is 100px (height is NOT fixed).
6th div is a footer has a fixed height e.g. 25px.

5th and 6th divs should be always on the bottom of the page (NOT sticky)

There is no problem when the 4th div (div_auto_height) has a lot of content and the page is just as long or longer than the screen.

The problem occurs when the page is shorter than the screen and the empty space comes after the 6th div. Then the 5th and 6th div are not where they supposed to be.

[image: This is the normal case]

The problem would be solved if one can get the height of the 4th div (div_auto_height) automatically adjusted to fill the empty space.

[image: This is what we need to have]

I have been trying to solve this problem in many ways without a decent solution.

**Not working solutions:**

- There are different screen resolutions, so min-height doesn't work
  with large screens without making the page a very long for small or
  wide screens.
- I haven't been able to get top and bottom positioning properties work properly
  because it makes divs 5 and 6 to come on top of 4th div (div_auto_height)

Here is a template for your modification:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>No title</title>
<style type="text/css">

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#div1 {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #123456;
}

#div2 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #345678;
}

#div3 {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #567890;
}

#div_auto_height {
    height: auto ;
    background-color: #789012;
}

#div5 {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #901234;
}

#div6 {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #123456;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
    <div id="div_auto_height">This div should adjust automatically</div>
    <div id="div5">Div 5</div>
    <div id="div6">Div 6</div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Quote**: _"...six divs one on the other"_.  What does that even mean?  Maybe you can provide a picture of what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Why can't you give a mi-height for 'div_auto_height'? I found your question not clear enough.

Comment: I'n heading to solve the problem with tables so it'll be as universal as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no CSS way to give a property the value "total screen height - some fixed pixels". Use Javascript.

Comment: Or you can simulate a table by using `display:table` etc. and giving the entire thing a height of 100%. But then all six rows will gain the same amount of extra vertical padding.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you should use javascript to solve this problem. There are a lot of easy-to-use javascript frameworks out there like jquery.

What you should do:

- give an id to your divs.
- using those ids find your divs - except for the fourth - and calculate their height
- get the height of the window
- set the 4th div's height by substracting the window height from the sum of your other divs height

And that's all! Tell me if you need some code.

**edit:** I didn't find the code but I remember that I used [jquery dimensions](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/). You can find example codes there!

Comment: This certainly solves the problem. It can also be solved easily by using tables. I was just wondering if there is a pure CSS solution to do the thing.

If you have the javascript code already in your files, I'm very thankful to get it from you. Thank you already!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most viable solution for you, but if you know a `max-height` for the 5th and 6th div, you can use `position: absolute` and `padding` (set to the `max-height` value) to achieve your result:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="div-25"></div>
    <div class="div-100"></div>
    <div class="div-25"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="fluid">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="div-25"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { 
    margin: 0; 
    height: 100%; }
div { width: 100%; }
#wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
.div-25 { 
    background: green;
    height: 25px; }
.div-100 { 
    background: grey;
    height: 50px; }
#content { padding: 0 0 150px; } /* Max Height */
.fluid { 
    background: red;
    height: 100px; }
#container { position: relative; }
.footer { 
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    min-height: 100px; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/jzdDU/

Comment: Sure. Please accept this answer if you feel like it solved your problem :)

Comment: It is close but still not quite there... This solution is quite fragile if 5th div's content gets some height.

Comment: Can't say I know a better solution. I agree with @mr lister's answer

Answer (score 0):

change

```
#div_auto_height {
   height: auto ;
   background-color: #789012;
}
```

to

```
#div_auto_height {
   height: 100% ;
   background-color: #789012;
}
```

or maybe you need this:

```
#div_auto_height {
   height: calc(100% - 275px); ;
   background-color: #789012;
}
```